Why is the mapping spectrum $F(\Sigma^{\infty}_{+} X, E)$ a homotopy commutative ring spectrum?
Given a homotopy commutative ring spectrum $E$ and an anima (or space in $\infty$-categorical setting) $X$, the mapping spectrum $F(\Sigma^{\infty}_{+} X, E)$ is also a homotopy commutative ring spectrum, but why? I feel the tricky part that is it's hard to say about the interaction between mapping spectrum and tensor products of spectra, thus the construction of the multiplication of this mapping spectrum is difficult.

Assuming that everything in $\infty$-category land these days straightforwardly generalizes the ordinary $1$-categorical situation, the reason should be that the mapping spectrum functor $E \mapsto [X, E]$ for $X$ a space is symmetric monoidal. I have no idea how difficult it is to make this idea work technically.

An analogy:
Keeping in mind the connections [spectra | abelian groups] and [anima | sets] we will try to gain some (perhaps flawed) intuition.
For a set $A$ and a ring $R$ we wish to make $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z}[A],R)$ into a ring.
At least for free groups one can use the free $\dashv$ forgetful adjunction $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z}[A],R)\cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(A,U(R))$ where the right-hand side inherits the pointwise product, turning it into a ring.
Another way to think about this is that $\mathbb{Z}[-]\colon \mathbf{Set}^\times\to \mathbf{Ab}^\otimes$ is op-lax monoidal, and there are natural maps of sets $A\to *$, as well as $A\to A\times A$, so there are   hence group homomorphisms
$$
\epsilon\colon \mathbb{Z}[A]\xrightarrow{a\in A\mapsto *}\mathbb{Z}[*]\xrightarrow{*\mapsto 1} \mathbb{Z}, \quad \Delta\colon \mathbb{Z}[A]\xrightarrow{\mathbb{Z}[\Delta_A]} \mathbb{Z}[A\times A]\xrightarrow{(a,a')\mapsto a\otimes a'} \mathbb{Z}[A]\otimes \mathbb{Z}[A], \quad 
$$
for which there is no good analog  $G\to \mathbb{Z}$ or $G\to G\otimes G$ for general abelian groups $G$.
We may now define a map using the multiplication $m\colon R\otimes R\to R$ as the composite
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z}[A],R)\otimes \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z}[A],R)&\to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z}[A]\otimes \mathbb{Z}[A],R\otimes R)\\
&\xrightarrow{\Delta_A^*\circ m_*} \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z}[A],R).
\end{align*}
This will be part of the "pointwise" ring structure, a unit is defined in the same spirit.
The stable setting:
Let $A,B,C$, and $D$ be spectra. Using the exponential notation convention for mapping spectra, there is a map
$$
B\wedge D\wedge A^B\wedge C^D\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}\wedge \tau\wedge \mathrm{id}} B\wedge A^B\wedge D\wedge C^D\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_B\wedge \mathrm{ev}_D} A\wedge C,
$$
where the evaluation map $\mathrm{ev}_B$ is the counit of the adjunction $(B\wedge -) \dashv(-)^B$, and similarly for $\mathrm{ev}_D$. Let us denote the adjoint by $\Psi\colon A^B\wedge C^D\to (A\wedge C)^{B\wedge D}$.
Returning to the setting of your question, let $X$ be an unpointed anima and $(E, \eta\colon \mathbb{S}\to E, \mu\colon E\wedge E\to E)$ be a spectrum with unit and multiplication maps. There is now a map
$$
\Delta\colon \Sigma_+^\infty X \xrightarrow{\Sigma^\infty_+\Delta_X} \Sigma_+^\infty (X\times X)\simeq \Sigma^\infty (X_+\wedge  X_+) \simeq \Sigma_+^\infty X\wedge \Sigma^\infty_+ X,
$$
which we use to define a multiplication on the mapping spectrum via
$$ 
\tilde \mu\colon E^{\Sigma_+^\infty X} \wedge E^{\Sigma_+^\infty X} \xrightarrow{\Psi} (E\wedge E)^{{\Sigma_+^\infty X}\wedge {\Sigma_+^\infty X}} \xrightarrow{\Delta^*\circ \mu_*}E^{\Sigma_+^\infty X}.
$$
Note that up to homotopy, it will not matter whether we pre- or post-compose first. The unit map is given by
$$
\Sigma^\infty_+X\to \mathbb{S}\xrightarrow{\eta} E,
$$
where the first map is induced from the unbased map $X\to *$. Finally, one can now show that $E^{\Sigma^\infty_+X}$ is a  homotopy (-commutative / -associative) ring spectrum if $E$ is.
Note:
There is probably a highly structured way in which $\Sigma^\infty_+\colon \mathrm{An}^\times \to \mathrm{Sp}^{\otimes}$ becomes an analog of "op-lax (symmetric) monoidal functor" in modern language. The reason for my not commenting on this is that I am simply not familiar with these notions.
